# MySQL secure-file-priv=""

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have next problem: I want to insert in a table an image (LONGBLOB). First of all, I successfully inserted the image from `C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads` (secure-file-priv = "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads") and then I set secure-file-priv="" in order to insert images from any location but NULL value is inserted. Can I upload images from any location? If so, how?

This is my table:

[image]

And this is the query:

```
INSERT INTO `soccertrackerdev`.`test`(`id`,`image`)
VALUES(4, LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/ionut.puiu/Desktop/Untitled.png'));
```

And the message after run the query is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you set this in your ini file, MySQL starts to obey:

```
secure-file-priv=""
```

(The setting for `local_infile` does not matter, in this case.)

This must be the difference between `empty` and `set to NULL` in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv):

- If empty, the variable has no effect. This is not a secure setting.
- If set to the name of a directory, the server limits import and export operations to work only with files in that directory. The directory must exist; the server does not create it.
- If set to NULL, the server disables import and export operations.

Comment: So, I can't upload images from any location. Am I right?

Comment: My test was successful,  When you test fails I will have a look (if you tell me your settings)

Comment: I only changed secure-file-priv to "" (empty string). I try to upload an image that have 391 bytes. Table configuration is presented in the post.